# Chrome extension "storage" permission not allowing content script to store data?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am currently working on a chrome extension where I need my content script to save data using "chrome.storage.local.set". I've looked online for tutorials and help but the only solution I can find is to add "storage" to my permissions, but I've done this.
Here is my manifest.json:

```
{
   "name": "Getting started example",
   "description": "This extension allows the user to change the background 
    color of the current page.",
   "version": "1.0",

   "browser_action" : {
       "default_icon": "icon.png",
       "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "permissions" : [
        "storage",
        "activeTab"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [{
        "js": ["contentscript.js"],
        "matches": ["*://csgofast.com/*"],
        "all_frames": true
    }],

    "web_accessible_resources": [
        "script.js"
    ],

    "manifest_version": 2
}
```

And below I have included a snippet of my content script:

```
function wholeSc(){
    chrome.storage.local.set({'csfast': "false"});
    running = true;
```

which when I run I get the error. 
[Picture of the error I get.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERCl5.png)

Comment: web_accessible_resources implies you're loading `script.js` in a `script` element so it runs in page context, not in the extension's content script context, which is why it can't use storage API.

Comment: Ahh thanks that makes sense is there anyway which I can communicate through the page to my extension? @wOxxOm ?

Comment: Yeah, use DOM messages e.g. [JS get varible defined in script tag (Google Extension)](//stackoverflow.com/a/46941198) or [Insert code into the page context using a content script](//stackoverflow.com/a/19312198)